# Add PWA to Vite project

Tags: reactjs, vite, vite-plugin-pwa

I want to have PWA for my project, I create a vite sample project with react and add **vite-plugin-pwa** version *17.5*

I use these lines for **vite.config.ts**, but when I deploy the website and open it in Safari and Add to Home Screen, it opens like a normal website not PWA.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    VitePWA({ registerType: 'autoUpdate' })
  ],
})
```

Comment: There could be a lot of things preventing it from working. I would suggest running a [lighthouse test](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/overview#devtools) on it and then check out the results for PWA.

Comment: @Rico Manifest could not be fetched, is empty, or could not be parsed, but the manifest is ok and I convert it to UTF8 with Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

You need to add manifest object inside VitePWA() in vite.config file.
Here's the link for detailed tutorial I found:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tP4tMCoSV0